# How to run a python script without leaving it on?

Tags: python, schedule

I am using the Schedule library from https://github.com/dbader/schedule like below:

```
def my_job():
    print('Doing job')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(my_job) # every midnight, do the job

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

However, this requires my script to be running 24/7. How can I make it so that I don't have to keep this script running, but the job is still performed daily?

Comment: You can't. _Something_ must be running in order to perform the job, so you'll either have to run the script at startup or use `cron` or a similar system scheduler.

Comment: you can't do this. Code has to run all time to do its job.

Comment: if you use `Linux` then you could use directly `cron` instead of sheduler. It runs all time and it may run any program (ie. script with only `my_job()` ) at `00:00` . `cron` should works also on Mac. WIndows should have own program/service for this. Long time ago there was command `at` in Windows` for this.

Comment: All major operating systems have a builtin scheduler that you can use. There are tons of examples on the net and if you have a problem superuser.com may be a good place to go.

Comment: As the others mentioned you have to have something running to schedule a job, but if your issue is that you constantly have a terminal open, you can send the process to the background and detach it from a terminal window using commands like `nohup` or simply `<cmd> &` on Unix/Linux but I'm not entirely sure for Windows